# Online Tool for Cran checks

Tags: r, cran

Even when I am afraid to be a bit off-topic, but I am not sure where else to ask this, sorry!

I am developing my R-package using a Linux system, hence I can run the `R CMD check --as-cran` command easily for Linux. For Windows it is also possible using a colleagues computer.

But how do you check your packages for MacOS? Or even worse, how to check for Solaris? I just ask, because I got an error there from the CRAN checks and most likely I won't be able to fix it without some try+error. But uploading new packages over and over until the error is fixed for MacOS can't be the solution...

Hence my question is, is there an online tool similar to [win-builder](http://win-builder.r-project.org/) (e.g. 'win-check.r-project.org' and 'macos-check.r-project.org' and so on), where you could check your package for all possible platforms, before submitting to cran? 
Unfortunately I do not know anybody who has a Mac, nor does Apple make it easy to install their OS on a x86 computer (I found the Hackintosh project, but it seems to be a bit shady...). Having such tools would make it much easier to fix certain issues in one's package.

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: you can set up a project on r-forge ... debugging is a pain in the butt, but you can at least find out whether and approximately how it's failing on different platforms ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is now R-Hub ([github page](https://github.com/r-hub/rhub)). Made possible by the R-Consortium.

> r-hub is a multi-platform build and check service for R packages. This
>   packages uses the r-hub API to connect to r-hub and start package
>   checks on various architectures.

Answer (score 6):

No.  There is currently no publicly available cross-platform checker available for R (with the possible exception of R-forge, which tends to be a bit unreliable)

Comment: Maybe something in the wings though? ;)

Comment: Thanks for the 'no' - of course a positive answer is always nicer, but at least it saves me now from further searches.. I will also have a look on R-forge (also thanks to @Ben).

Comment: @mdsumner nothing concrete, but this is a major pain point for package developers and it is something I think could be much less painful

Comment: Maybe travis on github could be configured to perform CHECK based on the most recent CRAN's test script?

Comment: @JanGorecki you'd need to install R-devel, which is possible, but painful

Comment: *"with the possible exception of R-forge"* How would one use R-forge to perform CRAN checks? Could you please expand on this...

Comment: I suggest an edit here. Your answer seems outdated given @phiver's answer. Doing so would give the consortium's platform a bit of a boost maybe as people follow advice of opinion leaders... Or did you not point to rhub on purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Guess a bit late to the party - nevertheless https://builder.r-hub.io/ would probably be the place to go!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Travis and Appveyor.

Both work very nicely along with GitHub. Take my R package for example https://github.com/SteffenMoritz/imputeTS

Whenever I update something there, Travis makes a Linux build and Appveyor a Windows build.

See:

**Travis-CI**
https://travis-ci.org/SteffenMoritz/imputeTS

and

**Appveyor**
https://ci.appveyor.com/project/steffenmoritz/imputeTS

For open source projects both built services are free.
You can see a lot of R packages on github using these two services.
(e.g. https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast)

For Mac I don't know of a build service.

Comment: What if it shows build passing but CRAN checks are actually showing an error?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above there's now R-hub. In particular see its [R client, the `rhub` package](https://r-hub.github.io/rhub/).

There's a part of the ["Get started" vignette about CRAN submissions](https://r-hub.github.io/rhub/articles/rhub.html#prepare-a-cran-submission) and [a screencast about the same topic](https://vimeo.com/329059890).

Disclaimer: I contribute to R-hub docs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the macOS builder project can be used to run package checks on a macOS platform (see https://mac.r-project.org/macbuilder/submit.html).